# SQL Query to find articles which belong to all selected tags

Tags: sql, select

I have 3 tables, articles, tags and article_tags. It's not that hard to find all articles which belong to one of the tags by using an IN() statement. However, I need to find only articles, which contain ALL selected tags...

Any ideas?
Thanks,
MC

Comment: How are you passing the tags in to the query?  Are they held in a table, or passed as a comma delimitered string? etc, etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say you have the list of the tags ID.

You can pass the total amount of tags to retrieve, and so you can filter the group by the number of tags you get :

Sample :

```
SELECT at.article_id
FROM article_tags at
WHERE at.tags_id in (2,3,4)
GROUP BY at.article_id
HAVING count(*) = 3
```

Comment: thanks, this pointed me the right way. however, it was incredible slow on more than 700.000 rows as i needed to add a second table for reference data.

indexes on 
article.id
tag.id
article_tag.articleid
article_tag.tagid

Using a join instead a self join solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your `articles` table has an `id` column, your `tags` table has an `id` column and your `article_tags` table has at least two columns `article_id` and `tag_id`, this should give you a list of ids of articles that have all the tags:

```
SELECT articles.id FROM articles
INNER JOIN article_tags ON articles.id = article_tags.article_id AND article_tags.tag_id IN (SELECT id FROM tags WHERE some criteria)
GROUP BY articles.id
HAVING COUNT(id) = (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM tags WHERE some criteria)
```